# Horovod and Tensorflow ambiguous error (train_on_batch)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, horovod

I'm trying to run distributed training with tensorflow.keras and horovod using a custom training loop (train_on_batch) with nvidia-docker on AWS p2.8xlarge. My code is a mess so posting it wouldn't be too useful. Here is a link to the [output](https://gist.github.com/amourav/dc20e9ce4ddfa60ca80b0fe261fe39a8) which doesn't appear very informative to me. The code runs without error using using `python run_trn.py`. Any advice on how to probe this error?

Relevant Horovod code

```py
import horovod.tensorflow.keras as hvd


gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
for gpu in gpus:
    tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True)
if gpus:
    tf.config.experimental.set_visible_devices(gpus[hvd.local_rank()], 'GPU')

...
        if self.horovod:
            lr_factor = hvd.size()
        else:
            lr_factor = 1
        
        optimizer = Adam(
            beta_1=self.adam_optimizer['beta1'],
            beta_2=self.adam_optimizer['beta2'],
            lr=self.learning_rate['initial_value'] * lr_factor,
            epsilon=self.adam_optimizer['epsilon'],
        )
        if self.horovod:
            optimizer = hvd.DistributedOptimizer(optimizer)
...
        if self.horovod:
            gcb = hvd.callbacks.BroadcastGlobalVariablesCallback(0)
            dcb = hvd.callbacks.BroadcastGlobalVariablesCallback(0)
            fecb = hvd.callbacks.BroadcastGlobalVariablesCallback(0)
            ccb = hvd.callbacks.BroadcastGlobalVariablesCallback(0)
            gcb.set_model(self.generator)
            dcb.set_model(self.discriminator)
            fecb.set_model(self.feature_extractor)
            ccb.set_model(self.model)
            gcb.on_train_begin()
            dcb.on_train_begin()
            fecb.on_train_begin()
            ccb.on_train_begin()
...
        if self.horovod:
            dataset = dataset.shard(hvd.size(), hvd.rank())
...
                if hvd.rank()==0:
                    self.helper.save_batch(epoch, step, batch, self.generator.model.predict,
                                        flatness, preview_path='sample_batches')
...
```

Here are my commands:

```
nvidia-docker run --privileged --gpus all -v $PWD:/opt/project -it horovod/horovod:0.20.0-tf2.3.0-torch1.6.0-mxnet1.6.0.post0-py3.7-cuda10.1 /bin/bash
cd /opt/project
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
pip install joblib scikit-image tqdm
horovodrun -np 8 -H localhost:8 python run_trn.py
```

At some point the gpus are being utilized.

```
ip-172-31-1-23       Wed May 12 00:26:19 2021  450.80.02
[0] Tesla K80        | 32'C,   0 % |  8447 / 11441 MB | root(8444M)
[1] Tesla K80        | 34'C,   0 % |  8447 / 11441 MB | root(8444M)
[2] Tesla K80        | 29'C,   0 % |  8447 / 11441 MB | root(8444M)
[3] Tesla K80        | 34'C,   0 % |  8447 / 11441 MB | root(8444M)
[4] Tesla K80        | 31'C,   0 % |  8447 / 11441 MB | root(8444M)
[5] Tesla K80        | 34'C,   0 % |  8447 / 11441 MB | root(8444M)
[6] Tesla K80        | 37'C,   0 % |  8447 / 11441 MB | root(8444M)
[7] Tesla K80        | 38'C,   0 % |  8447 / 11441 MB | root(8444M)
```